# Filter only certain categories of log records using sed

Tags: windows, sed, text-processing

Please help me understand how can I use *sed* to reduce log files like this

```
2017-06-13 11:47:05.121 [INFO] : Finished obj.clickButton('A1');
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2432
2017-06-13 11:47:13.807 [INFO] : start=1497347223552  end=1497347233576
2017-06-13 11:47:13.827 [INFO] : start=1497347223552  end=1497347233576
2017-06-13 11:47:13.882 [INFO] : start=1497347223552  end=1497347233576
2017-06-13 11:47:14.695 [ERROR]: Caught exception waiting 
STACK:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: window.obj is undefined
Command duration or timeout: 367 milliseconds
2017-06-13 11:47:14.863 [INFO] : start=1497347234059  end=1497347234690
2017-06-13 11:47:15.192 [INFO] : start=1497347234059  end=1497347234690
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2433
2017-06-13 11:47:15.192 [INFO] : start=1497347234059  end=1497347234690
```

...into files which contain only two categories of records:

**Divisor of records:**

```
(^\d\d\d\d.\d\d.\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d)
```

**Category 1:**

```
Processing index
```

- output as it is

**Category 2:** (multi-line regex):

```
Caught exception.*timeout: (\d+) milliseconds
```

- output `\1 ms` (even time stamp is not needed)

**Expected result after processing:**

```
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2432
367 ms
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2433
```

I currently know only basic *sed* usage (`s/search/replace/opt`) and despite reading the manual I am not sure how to compose set of commands with the above effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those basic sed commands are all you need to use sed correctly. For anything else you should be using awk instead.

If this isn't all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements:

```
$ awk '/index/{print} /duration/{print $(NF-1), $NF}' file
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2432
367 milliseconds
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2433
```

A couple of ways to print "ms" instead of "milliseconds":

```
$ awk '/index/{print} /duration/{print $(NF-1), "ms"}' file
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2432
367 ms
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2433

$ awk '/index/{print} /duration/{print $(NF-1), substr($NF,1,1) substr($NF,length($NF)-6,1)}' file
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2432
367 ms
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2433

$ awk 'BEGIN{abbr["milliseconds"]="ms"} /index/{print} /duration/{print $(NF-1), abbr[$NF]}' file
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2432
367 ms
2017-06-13 11:47:05.137 [INFO] : Processing index 2433
```

Which one is right for you all depends on what your input can contain.

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you. I can see how effectively awk can be used in this case. Finally, I worked out this with sed, because I found it beneficial to hold a context using `h` command. (Not shown in the above example.) I will accept your awk solution with one additional question: Is it also equally simple to change `milliseconds` into `ms` as expected in the example? Should I just replace `$NF` with `"ms"`?.

Comment: No, **never** use `h` or any other sed constructs except s, g, and p (with -n) or you are **literally** using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. People use those other constructs today strictly for the mental exercise, not to seriously write software, since an equivalent awk solution will be clearer, more efficient, more portable, easier to maintain/enhance, and better in every other meaningful way. Yes, it's trivial to write ms instead of milliseconds but is that the only unit you care about or can there be nanosecond, seconds, minutes, etc. in the input?

Comment: I added a few different ways to convert "milliseconds" to "ms" for you to choose from. There are other approaches too but those are the 3 most likely for one of them to be what you're looking for I think.

Comment: Thank you for teaching :). I walked through awk tutorial and I can say awk is a great tool. It is easy to learn and it gives me full control over the processing, unlike the magic with `h` in sed. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Beware of awk tutorials as most of them are complete nonsense. Just read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to really use awk.

Comment: For the benefit of the guy who wrote the book and kindly makes a copy available online for reference and also spends massive amounts of time and effort on providing and supporting GNU awk and gets paid nothing except what he makes from sales of the book - **buy the book**!